# troubleshooting generic error when running `fontcustom compile`

Tags: ubuntu, webfonts, fontforge

I'm working on a pre-existing project that uses `fontcustom` to build some custom icons.  I'm not the one that created the icons, I'm on the deployment side.  The designer that created the icons is able to "compile" fine on his Mac, but I haven't been able to get it to work on a `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS` box, from which I'm trying to automate all build and deployment steps for this particular app.

I'm using `fontcustom v-1.3.8`.  This was installed using the instructions on its github page:

```
sudo apt-get install fontforge
wget http://people.mozilla.com/~jkew/woff/woff-code-latest.zip
unzip woff-code-latest.zip -d sfnt2woff && cd sfnt2woff && make && sudo mv sfnt2woff /usr/local/bin/
gem install fontcustom
```

When I run `fontforge --version` I get:

```
Copyright (c) 2000-2014 by George Williams. See AUTHORS for Contributors.
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 with many parts BSD <http://fontforge.org/license.html>. Please read LICENSE.
 Based on sources from 02:23 UTC  5-Apr-2016-ML-D.
 Based on source from git with hash: 94038cd93f463ae5020b722a518c65abc843a79a
no xdefs_filename!
TESTING: getPixmapDir:/usr/share/fontforge/pixmaps
TESTING: getShareDir:/usr/share/fontforge
TESTING: GResourceProgramDir:/usr/bin
trying default theme:/usr/share/fontforge/pixmaps/resources
fontforge 02:23 UTC  5-Apr-2016
libfontforge 20160405
```

Now, when I actually run `fontcustom compile --debug` I get:

```
       debug  Using settings from `fontcustom.yml`.
       debug  Using options:
                {:input=>{:vectors=>"vectors", :templates=>"templates"},
                :output=>
                 {:fonts=>"fonts",
                  :"_font-icons.scss"=>"../../scss/base/icons",
                  :"_icon-font.scss"=>"../../scss/base/icons",
                  :css=>"fonts",
                  :preview=>"fonts"},
                :config=>"fontcustom.yml",
                :templates=>["_font-icons.scss", "_icon-font.scss"],
                :font_name=>"icons",
                :font_design_size=>16,
                :font_em=>512,
                :font_ascent=>448,
                :font_descent=>64,
                :css_selector=>".icon-{{glyph}}",
                :preprocessor_path=>nil,
                :autowidth=>false,
                :no_hash=>true,
                :debug=>true,
                :force=>false,
                :quiet=>false}
       debug  Copyright (c) 2000-2014 by George Williams. See AUTHORS for Contributors.
               License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
               with many parts BSD <http://fontforge.org/license.html>. Please read LICENSE.
               Based on sources from 02:23 UTC  5-Apr-2016-ML-D.
               Based on source from git with hash: 94038cd93f463ae5020b722a518c65abc843a79a
              Save Failed
              Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fontcustom-1.3.8/lib/fontcustom/scripts/generate.py", line 99, in <module>
                  font.generate(fontfile + '.ttf')
              EnvironmentError: Font generation failed
       error  `fontforge` compilation failed.
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fontcustom-1.3.8/lib/fontcustom/generator/font.rb:92:in `create_fonts'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fontcustom-1.3.8/lib/fontcustom/generator/font.rb:20:in `generate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fontcustom-1.3.8/lib/fontcustom/base.rb:50:in `start_generators'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fontcustom-1.3.8/lib/fontcustom/base.rb:22:in `compile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fontcustom-1.3.8/lib/fontcustom/cli.rb:77:in `compile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fontcustom-1.3.8/bin/fontcustom:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/fontcustom:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/fontcustom:23:in `<main>'
```

I have a feeling I am missing some library.  Most info I've found online is related to Mac and often references reinstalling fontforge and/or making sure various lib dependencies are installed.  I've tried installing `python-fontforge`, `ttfautohint`, `ruby-dev`, and `woff-tools` and still no love.

I'm runninng `ruby 1.9.3p484`.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? This lack of useful error message in FontForge is a bit frustrating.

Comment: @AgDude sorry, I don't recall with what happened with this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with Fontcustom itself, but with Fontforge.

Homebrew installs a different (read: newer) version of fontforge than `apt-get` does.

To correct this, you have to manually install the correct fontforge version on Linux.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fontforge/fontforge
sudo apt-get update
```